# How to configure web server to run with another name instead of 'localhost'

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

I have this url in my local web server :

```
"http://localhost:9698/AppName/Default.aspx"
```

But i want to configure the name of `localhost:9698`, something like `MyServer`:

```
"http://MyServer/AppName/Default.aspx"
```

I had try to work with Binding... in IIS but it doesn't worked.
What should i do?

Comment: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/04/thinking-outside-box-with-aspnet.html and goto --> run --> drivers --> etc --> hosts open in note page check it  hope this will help you ..;)

Comment: `localhost:9698` is not a hostname. `localhost` is. `9698` is the port the site apparently runs on. How is your site currently hosted? In IIS, or IIS Express? Did you bind the site in IIS to a hostname? If not, you don't have to change anything, only the client which refers to `localhost`: change that into `MyServer`. This of course only works if the client recognizes your server with the name `MyServer`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm using IIS, and only i want to have MyServer:1234 instead of localhost:1234, also i'm using my web application on the server

Comment: You usually _don't_  have to change anything. Just use http://servername/ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The above is how you can do development work locally (e.g. your desktop computer) - either using the VS Dev server or via IIS Express.

Assuming you want to **simply test on a development machine** e.g. Win 7/8:

- If you have [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), you can [edit your `hosts` file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) so you can use a name other than `localhost`.

> Warning: do this at your own risk - undo or comment out your changes after you've
>   done debugging/testing. Also, some AV programs explicitly block
>   editing this important file (HOSTS). If that is the case, you'll have
>   to consult with your AV provider....

- You can then do the binding you are referring to with, or without using `host headers` as necessary

If the above is mysterious to you, or doesn't make sense, you'll need to get into networking concepts - re: "localhost", 127.0.01, ip addressing, etc....and depending on the full context of your question, DNS.

Also if it gets to that point, its probably better to move your question over to [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)